# Google Adwords API adding campaign

Tags: google-ads-api

May be my question will look dumb but i'm  new in using AdWords API hence i got some problems.
I'm using Ruby to add campaigns.
So i created my MCC account, there I have a client.I'm using SANDBOX.
so i create new API object like this:

```
creds = {

     'developerToken' => 'user@domain.com++USD',
     'useragent' => 'Sample User Agent',
     'password' => 'password',
     'email' => 'user@domain.com',
     'clientEmail' => 'client_1+user@domain.com',
     'applicationToken' => 'IGNORED',
     'environment' => 'SANDBOX',
}
@adwords = AdWords::API.new(AdWords::AdWordsCredentials.new(creds))
```

then i add some campaigns
  and finally i get an answer that campaign is added BUT i don't understand where i can see it. I have my my MCC account but i don't understand where these campaigns will appear if i use sandbox not production. Can anybody explain me how to test on SANDBOX?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code to add the campaigns?

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't provide a front end for the Sandbox to check that code is working. I usually end up just uploading test campaigns to my own production account.

However, if you don't want to do that then there's a Java application that can be pointed at the sandbox to see what's in an account. It can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-java/wiki/SandboxAccountViewer

Answer (score 0):

You can view campaigns in [Campaign Performance Report](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/appendix/reports.html#campaign) (retrievable in XML).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write script which fetches campaigns from sandbox. Whether you are using `adwords4r` or the new `google-adwords-api` gem, both of them provide example scripts for various tasks. Here is [how to fetch campaigns in google-adwords-api](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-ruby/source/browse/trunk/adwords_api.savon/examples/v201101/get_all_campaigns.rb), which is probably what's you're looking for.